# Metaplex JavaScript SDK:: Installation vulnerabilities

Tags: npm, blockchain, solana, metaplex

## npm audit report

axios  0.8.1 - 0.27.2
Severity: moderate
Axios Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wf5p-g6vw-rhxx
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @metaplex-foundation/js@0.19.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/aptos/node_modules/axios
aptos  <=1.13.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of axios
node_modules/aptos
@irys/sdk  <=0.1.12
Depends on vulnerable versions of aptos
node_modules/@irys/sdk
@metaplex-foundation/js  >=0.20.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @irys/sdk
node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

If I were to run "npm audit fix --force" it just makes it go even bad. Any idea how to fix this?

How to fix this issue in order to use the  "@metaplex-foundation/js" library properly?